# What excellent university DSP programs exist and what makes them excellent?

Tags: education

In the same vein as [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/books-that-explain-dsp-well-to-those-not-directly-in-engineering) question, but making sure to abide by [Good Subjective/Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), what DSP programs are out there that are excellent and why?

Please give concrete examples or at least a cursory explanation for what makes them good/thorough, and stand out from other programs at different universities.

Comment: Mohammad, since the question has been migrated, you might want to generalize it, and for instance ask what criteria make a good program, or how to find if a program is good or not.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Hi Charles. Honestly, not really... I want to know what good universities exist for Digital Signal Processing (DSP), and what makes them good. To be frank I am surprised it has been migrated to here to be honest, since dsp.SE has the requisite people who would actually know. I would not mind making it clearer vis-a-vis DSP, but that is honestly my question.

Comment: As you want, but I guess it was migrated because the crowd there couldn't really answer it specifically. I think @CyberMen's answer is quite good, and could be easily generalizable. I believe it's a hard question to answer as it is, I couldn't do it for my own field, at best, I could tell you if my own program was good (with a huge obvious bias). Good luck with your search anyway! :)

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Thank you. I believe that if everyone gave their own experiences we might have attained a good post. I know its hard for individuals to answer it, which is why I asked the hivemind! :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand your approach when posting to dsp.SE, but since you're now on Academia.SE, maybe some people will overlook your question just because it seems targeted to DSP. You might get very useful tips by reformulating sth along the lines "What qualifies a program as excellent? How to objectively compare two programs?" and mention that you're particularly interested in DSP programs.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, lets assume you're talking about graduate programs. X being such a specialized program would only be available at that level of study.

In a nutshell:

1. Large list of cross listed (undegrad/grad) or only grad courses in all areas of study. You still need to have courses that can advance your overall knowledge of engineering.
2. Large variety of courses in your area of study. (If your studying DSP, its not enough to just take a DSP class, you may find it relevant to study data compression, machine learning, Free-space laser communications.) This also means you wouldn't have to complete a large number of independent study programs.
3. Large Number of Faculty in your research area. If you are interested in studying music signal processing, you would want to do research with a professor who has experience in that field. If there are 10 professors, you could be more selective about who to work with or who will be the best fit for your research area.

As for schools with decent program: **Binghamton University**, while it is not well known outside of New York, its master's programs is well structured, large number of faculty in EE at least 3-4 DSP professors, 10-20 graduate level courses offered a semester and large number of those are DSP related.